# How to inherit and filter data from a Django model

Tags: python, django, model

How to inherit and filter data from the base model in Django?

For example, my base model goes like this:

```
class Customers(models.Model):
     Time_Registered = models.DateField(blank=False)
     Number = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     Name = models.CharField(max_length=250)  
     Locations = models.ForeignKey(Locations, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I want to do is create another model that contains customer information related to one location, such as:

```
Class Canada(Customers):
    class Meta:
    proxy = True
  # filter by Canada'
```

Comment: once you inherited, you can access all attr of base class,  like : Canada.objects.filter(Number='32423')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/#modifying-a-manager-s-initial-queryset).

You can customize the example in the documentation to your needs, for example:

```
class CanadaCustomerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Adapt the query to your needs
        return super().get_queryset().filter(location__name="Canada")
```

And then you would instantiate the manager in one of your models (either `Customers` or `Canada`).

Note that you do not really need to define a new proxy model if you just want to define a custom manager. For example you could use it in your `Customers` model like so:

```
class Customers(models.Model):
    Time_Registered = models.DateField(blank=False)
    Number = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=250)  
    Locations = models.ForeignKey(Locations, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    from_canada = CanadaCustomerManager()
```

And then use it, for example, to retrieve objects:

```
>>> Customers.from_canada.all()
```

---

As a side note, using Django, the convention is to declare model classes as singular nouns (i.e. `Customer` and not `Customers`). This is because each instance of the model represents a single customer, even though the db table contains all your customers.

Moreover, attribute names are usually declared without using Capital Letters (i.e. `time_registered` instead of `Time_Registered`).